# Instantion of classes from other OSGi bundles

Tags: osgi, classloader

I have two types of bundles:

1. Launcher:  A bundle responsible for launching code in the "ammo" bundle.
2. Ammo:  A bundle that implements a pre-defined interface.

A container will have only have one Launcher, but may have several Ammo bundles.  The Ammo bundles depend on the Launcher bundle.  I just want the Launcher to instantiate a class in an Ammo bundle.  But the Launcher's class loader can't find it.  What's the best way to get the appropriate classloader?

Note:  I need the ability to add and remove different types of Ammo, so the Launcher can't really specify the Ammo as a dependency.

Comment: If the launcher is responsible for launching code in the ammo bundle, then launcher has a dependency on ammo, not the other way around.  You need to follow @Balazs advice and make an OSGi based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create an AmmoFactory interface and register factory OSGi services from each Ammo bundle.

On the Launcher side you can track the registered services and instantiate the objects with the help of the factory instances.

Instead of classloading hacks, design your solution based on OSGi services.